# Storing byte[] in class

Tags: java, arrays

For storing a byte array in class, do I just copy the array or just pass a reference?

E.g.

```
class MyClass {

    public MyClass(int size, Byte buf[]) {
        this.size = size;
        this.buffer = buf;
    }

    private int size;
    private Byte buffer[];
}
```

or,

```
class MyClass {

    public MyClass(int size, Byte buf[]) {
        this.size = size;
        this.buffer = buf;
    }

    private int size;
    private Byte buffer[] = new Byte[size];
}
```

or,

```
class MyClass {

    public MyClass(int size, Byte buf[]) {
        this.size = size;
        this.buffer = copyOf(buf, 5);
    }

    private int size;
    private Byte buffer[];
}
```

I am confused whether I need to really copy the array or just store reference?

Comment: The seconde one will create an array of size `0` then override it with `buf`. The last will create a copy, **this is good for immutability** as the array references will be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't copy the array, then any changes made to the source array will affect the new array inside the class. That is probably not what you want.

Also: You should probably use a `byte[]`, not a `Byte[]`. (A `Byte` is a wrapper object around a `byte`, and an array of `Byte` objects uses much more memory than one of `byte` primitives.

Comment: Hello, I don't care about the source e.g. I have a string and I do `"HelloWorld".getBytes()`. Can I simply assign the bytes without copying? Can you give examples of both ways please?

Comment: Sure. "HelloWorld".getBytes() creates a new byte array. If you just assign that to your field, then there's no other reference, and hence no need for a copy.

Comment: As for examples, I guess my first example shows how to assign it directly and third one shows copying and second one is incorrect?

Comment: The second one is initializing an array and then overwriting it with another one. That's complete nonsense. The 3rd one is a best practice if you think someone else still has a handle to your array. The 1td is good if you know there is no such other handle.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decide what your class contract is.

1. If you copy the content, you are certain that the calling code won't modify the array unexpectedly, but it's slower.
2. If you *don't* copy the content, it's faster but if the calling code modifies the array your class may behave unexpectedly.

So you need to answer these questions:

- Is it ok for some code to modify the content of the array after it has been passed to your class?
- If it's not ok, do you want to copy the content or simply put a note in the javadoc to document the fact that any subsequent modifications to the array may break the class?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the reference, your array will be changing whenever your original array changes.
If you only want the values inside your class, you should choose the second method. Because that way the two arrays are "separated".